# Devexpress combo-box that share the same text-box and return different value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

Below is the issue which I have to resolve.

Behavior Required:
On selecting an item from combobox, it activates the textbox to insert a value and the textbox value will be send to gridview. I want to seperate the textbox value into 2 different values and I require one textbox and gridview cod to read either of the text instead of both.

```
 where a.EQPTYPE LIKE '%"+tb1.Text+"%' and EQPID LIKE '%"+tb1.Text+"%'
```

ASPX Code:

```
     <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="box1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Kit_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedIndex="0" Caption="Selection :">
                    <Items>
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text ="Selected Item" Value="0" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="EQPTYPE" Value="1" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="EQPID" Value="2" />
                    </Items>
          </dx:ASPxComboBox>

            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" Width="170px" CssClass="auto-style6">
            </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

C# Code:

```
    protected void Kit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (box1.SelectedItem.Text == "EQPTYPE")
                {
                    tb1.Enabled = true;
                    tb1.Text = String.Empty;
                }
                else if(box1.SelectedItem.Text == "EQPID")
                {
                    tb1.Enabled = true;
                    tb1.Text = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    tb1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Please guide, thank you!

Comment: What kind of expected values contained in `tb1.Text` (currently still unclear)? For your SQL query, you can use 2 parameters such like `@substr1` & `@substr2`, then split input strings based from selected item (again, I suggest to avoid concatenated strings for queries to prevent SQL injection).

Comment: basically for selected eqptype , the textbox will return string value, and for selected eqpid, the textbox will return int value. the problem that i raised earlier is solved, i will change the sql query to parameterized query after this issue solved.

Comment: Your current query uses `AND`, which implies both `EQPTYPE` and `EQPID` must have values to proceed. Are you actually want to include all options, or just let user select one of `EQPTYPE` or `EQPID` but not both? If the second one is true, then declare `SqlParameter` with corresponding data types and assign them.

Comment: yes, let user select one of EQPTYPE or EQPID, textbox search using sqlparameter?